# Pandas: Update record if exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df. It has two columns `category` and `description`. Neither `category` or `description` are part of the index.

I am looping around some other data then adding categories (variable=temp_category) one by one to my dataframe. If the `category` already exists, I want to get the `description` from the dataframe, append some text to it and then update the record.

If the record doesn't exist I am simply appending a new record with df.append

I'm using this to determine if the category already exists in the dataframe:

`if df.ix[df['category'] == temp_category]['category'].count() > 0:`

My questions are:

- How do I update the record?
- Is the `if` statement above the simplest way to see if `temp_category` exists in the dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to do this for alot of data? Searching DataFrame without index and appending is slow (Q(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `pandas.merge()` is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"c":["A", "B", "C"], "d":["d1", "d2", "d3"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"c":["A", "B", "D", "E"], "d":["xx1", "xx2", "xx3", "xx4"]})

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="c", how="outer")
df.fillna("", inplace=True)
df["d"] = df["d_x"] + df["d_y"]
df.drop(["d_x", "d_y"], axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

output:

```
  c      d
0  A  d1xx1
1  B  d2xx2
2  C     d3
3  D    xx3
4  E    xx4
```